# Can not instantiate any component from JavaScript in lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, create-component

I can not instantiate any component from JavaScript in lightning.

**1**. I took a specific component `namespace:ModuleCard` and checked that when I include it statically (just put `<namespace:ModuleCard/>` in markup) I actually see it without any problems.

**2**. I added the following line in my markup:

`<aura:dependency resource="markup://namespace:WizardModuleCard" type="COMPONENT"/>`

**3**. I made sure that I am using `getCallback` in the right place:

```
                 const wrapperComponent = this.component.find("modulesList");
                 $A.getCallback(function() {
                    $A.createComponent(
                        "namespace:WizardModuleCard",
                        {
                            
                        },
                        function(newComponent, status, errorMessage) {
                            if (status === "SUCCESS") {
                                const body = wrapperComponent.get("v.body");
                                body.push(newComponent);
                                wrapperComponent.set("v.body", body);
                            } else if (status === "ERROR") {
                                console.log("ERROR: " + errorMessage);
                            } else /*if (status === "INCOMPLETE")*/ {
                                console.log("INCOMPLETE")
                            }
                        }
                    );
                })();
```

**4**. I put a breakpoint in Chrome dev tools on the line:

```
console.log("ERROR: " + errorMessage);
```

and read the `errorMessage`. Here it is:

> "Unknown component 'markup://namespace:WizardModuleCard'."

I used the following resources to try to solve the issue:

[Unknown component 'markup://'… on $A.createComponent](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/209504/unknown-component-markup-on-a-createcomponent)

[aura:dependency documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_tag_dependency.htm)

I am very stuck. If you had the same problem and know how to solve it, that would be amazing.

By the way, my question states `any component`. That is because I performed the same procedure as described above (for `WizardModuleCard`) for two other components. One of them is used already in my development for maybe a few months and I was able to access and instantiate it everywhere except now. Another component I created just after finding out about the current problem and I was not able to create that new component dynamically as well.

Also I checked once more that I have `Enable secure and persistent browser caching to improve performance` option disabled.

[image]

After trying to instantiate the component for something like 10 to 15 times (I just run and run the code which should create the component dynamically, I added the code above) I got this `errorMessage`:

> "Definition does not exist on the client for descriptor:markup://namespace:WizardModuleCard. Client side caches have been cleared. Please reload the page."

Now I keep getting this message instead of

> "Unknown component 'markup://namespace:WizardModuleCard'."

The code which I provided above works fine if I run it from the beginning in `onInit`.

Comment: Are you sure you used the right namespace?

Comment: @sfdcfox, absolutely sure. Using that namespace allows me to incorporate the component statically (by putting it directly in `.cmp` html). And the component displays successfully, there are no errors, no warnings, it looks as expected.

Comment: Okay, are you using Lightning Out? That's the only time you need aura:dependency.

Comment: @sfdcfox, no. I am not using Lightning Out. But it did not work without the addition of `<aura:dependency/>` (as well as with it). I will remove it and try again. Thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the following.

I was using `d3.js` to add actions on button click this way:

```
const button = d3.select("#myButton");
button.on("mousedown", function() {
 //here I try to create a lightning component dynamically
});
```

Now instead of such an approach I am adding a click listener in markup:

```
<div id="myButton" onclick="{!c.addModuleCard}"> Add a module card </div>
```

**FIY**

It is convenient to create a class which will work with the component, then save an instance of this class into a `window` object in this way `window.pageInfo = info`. This `window` object will be created for each component separately and now when I will need to access some data in `addModuleCard` I will be able to get it using the `window.pageInfo` object.

It is for those who will encounter the same problem as I did and will be stuck by not knowing how to transfer the data into a different client-side function.

I am sorry, since I did not provide the whole code and those who tried to help me were not actually able to do so because of this.

Comment: To be precise, you problem was that you didn't wrap your callback in `$A.getCallback()`. Just fought with this shit for 2 hours. Up yours SFDC.